# Assigning a return value of a function in heap

Tags: c, malloc

I am having trouble with assigning a return value of a function in **heap** part of the program. When I tried it in main, it gives an error **"Segmentation fault"**. I believe it is because of the size of my array, which is the return value that I mentioned earlier because when I make my max_size smaller, the code works correctly (I think up to 45000). When I call the function in main, it uses the memory of stack, which is much smaller than memory of heap. Therefore I tried to call the function in heap and make the assignment in there but the compiler gave an error

```
deneme.c:6:15: error: initializer element is not constant
 int *primes = listPrimes(1000000, &size);
```

After that I did some research and found out that stack is 8 MB memory, which is around 8000000 bytes. Then I estimated my array size as  using the prime number theorem (up to 1000000, there are approximately 200000 primes) and `sizeof(int) = 4 bit` value so it gives 100000 bytes, which is much less than 8 MB. Therefore I have two questions in mind:

> **1.** Why the compiler gives segmentation fault error although my array size is not too large?
>
> **2.** How can I make the assigment in heap instead of main in order to avoid this problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include "mathlib.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *listPrimes(int max_size, int *size) {
        *size = 1;
        int *result = malloc(*size * sizeof(int));
        int i;
        int index = 1;
        // Finding the list of primes using a sieve algorithm:
        int *nums = malloc(max_size*sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < max_size; i++) {
                nums[i] = i;
        }
        result[0] = 2;
        int j = 2;
        while (j < max_size) {
                int k = j;
                while (j*k <= max_size) {
                        nums[j*k] = 0;
                        k++;
                }
                if (j == 2) {
                        j++;
                        *size = *size + 1;
                        result = realloc(result, *size * sizeof(int));
                        result[index++] = nums[j];
                }
                else {
                        j += 2;
                        if (nums[j] != 0) {
                                *size = *size + 1;
                                result = realloc(result, *size * sizeof(int));
                                result[index++] = nums[j];
                        }
                }
        }
        return result;
}
```

and main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mathlib.h"

int size = 0;
int *primes = listPrimes(1000000, &size);

int main() {
        printf("size = %d\n", size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                printf("%d th prime is %d\n", i+1, primes[i]);
        }
        free(primes);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quote: "sizeof(int) = 4 bit" notice: it's 4 bytes - not bits

Comment: (a) What is `mathlib.h`? (b) Are you compiling this with a C++ compiler (like Visual Studio’s), not a C compiler? `int *primes = listPrimes(1000000, &size);` is not valid at file scope in C.

Comment: `int *primes = listPrimes(1000000, &size);` you can't call a function when initializing a global variable. The code must be inside `main`

Comment: Change `int *primes = listPrimes(1000000, &size);` to `int *primes = NULL;`, then add `*primes = listPrimes(1000000, &size);` as the first line inside main.

Comment: Whenever you call `malloc` or `realloc`, you should immediately check the result. (For example, if the the result is NULL, print a message and exit the program.) This would tell you immediately whether your program is failing because it tried to allocate too much memory or because of some other problem.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, in my first attempt, I tried to call it in main and got "Segmentation fault" error. This is the final state of my code so I posted this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unsigned int` for `j, k` and `max_size` in listPrimes and it works properly . Below is the tested code:

```
// #include "mathlib.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int size = 0;

int *
listPrimes (unsigned int max_size, int *size)
{
  *size = 1;
  int *result = malloc (*size * sizeof (int));
  int i;
  int index = 1;
  // Finding the list of primes using a sieve algorithm:
  int *nums = malloc (max_size * sizeof (int));
  for (i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
    {
      nums[i] = i;
    }
  result[0] = 2;
  unsigned int j = 2;
  while (j < max_size)
    {
      unsigned int k = j;
      while (j * k <max_size)
    {
      nums[j * k] = 0;
      k++;
    }
      if (j == 2)
    {
      j++;
      *size = *size + 1;
      result = realloc (result, *size * sizeof (int));
      result[index++] = nums[j];
    }
      else
    {
      j += 2;
      if (nums[j] != 0)
        {
          *size = *size + 1;
          result = realloc (result, *size * sizeof (int));
          result[index++] = nums[j];
        }
    }
    }
   free(nums);
   return result;
}

int
main ()
{
  int *primes = listPrimes (1000000, &size);
  printf ("size = %d\n", size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d th prime is %d\n", i + 1, primes[i]);
    }
  free (primes);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Arsenic Also you don't `free(nums)` at the end of `listPrimes()`. That's one helluva memory leak.

Comment: Oh, I forgot it, thank you very much for mentioning it too @Persixty

Comment: This does not fix the problem that `nums[j*k] = 0;` writes beyond the end of the `nums` array when `j*k` equals `max_size`. Possibly changing the types of `max_size`, `j`, and `k` happened to move things around in memory so that the write beyond the end of the array did not happen to cause a crash. But that merely disguised the error; the error is still present.

Answer (score 1):

`nums` is allocated to have `max_size` elements, so the index of its last element is `max-size-1`.

This loop:

```
while (j*k <= max_size) {
     nums[j*k] = 0;
     k++;
}
```

may access an element with index `j*k` that equals `max_size`, thus writing beyond the end of the array. The loop should be limited to `j*k < max_size`.

Regarding your second question, the size of the `result` array is determined while finding the primes and is not readily calculable in advance, so it cannot easily be allocated prior to calling `listPrimes`. It could be done by evaluating the [*prime-counting function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), but that is likely more than you want to do for this project.